What do you do if you accidentally put down Weed and Feed a couple of hours before it rained heavily?
I was planning on putting down Weed and Feed fertilizer on my lawn. Since the instructions for my brand of fertilizer (Jonathan Green Weed and Feed) say to make sure that there's no rain forecasted for 48 hours, I checked the weather report and saw that rain was predicted for Friday afternoon (today is Tuesday). I figured that, if I put it down now, I'd be fine. Unfortunately, the weather report was completely wrong, and there ended up being a heavy thunderstorm about two hours after I put it down. (They since changed the weather report to no longer include rain on Friday, just for today).
I do have some left over, and I was trying to figure out when I can safely put it down again.
A few other notes:

This hopefully doesn't sound too "shallow," but I am expecting company over the weekend and was hoping to improve the weed situation before they come.
I still have some of the Weed and Feed in my spreader (I put too much of it in and didn't have a chance to transfer it back to the bag yet, which I'm also not sure how to safely do, especially given that the bag somehow developed a hole in the bottom when I picked it up). I realize that that's probably not a great situation - I guess chalk it up to a novice error.
I'm in the southern Chicago region. It's quite hot here right now (80s and 90s), but fall and winter are also coming up. I'm somewhat concerned about the lawn getting too much nitrogen too close to winter.
I am planning on putting down winterizer fertilizer towards the middle or end of October (also Jonathan Green brand).

So, my question: when can I safely put it down again? Can I put the stuff I have left in the spreader down soon, or do I need to transfer that back to the bag somehow and do something else about the weeds?

Wait and see. Probably the waiting time is just for the weed part, so eventually you buy a product "only weed", or the "weed and reseed"). If the weed problem is low, just ignore. (and a recommendation: separate products are far better).

I can't find out what the weedkillers used in this preparation are because I'm not in the States, but with most combined treatments, the weedkiller is unlikely to do much and especially not within a week or two. I wouldn't risk applying more at this stage, wait and see what its like in a month, but note that separate lawn weedkiller is usually more effective than the combined products. Just cut the lawn before your guests come, that will help it look better.
